# Pointer in C only updates once when method is called

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, methods

I am doing a program to mimic the hare and turtle race. I dont understand why my pointer for the turtle movement only updates once when the condition is met multiple times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define SIZE 70

void turtleMove(char raceTrack[SIZE], char *tPtr);

int main()
{
    char raceTrack[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        raceTrack[i] = ' ';
    }

    char *tPtr = raceTrack;

    for(int i = 0; i <=10; i++)
    {
        turtleMove(raceTrack, tPtr);
    }

}
void turtleMove(char raceTrack[SIZE], char *tPtr)
{
    srand(time(0));

    int num = rand() % 10 + 1;
    printf("%d\n", num);

    if(num >= 1 && num <= 5)
    {
        printf("Fast plod\n");
        *tPtr = ' ';
        tPtr += 3;
        *tPtr = 'T';

        for(int i = 0; i <SIZE; i++)
        {
            printf("%c,", raceTrack[i]);

        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

I want it to do this for example:

2
Fast plod
 , , ,T, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

5
Fast plod
 , , , , , , ,T, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
etc...

Instead it's doing:

2
Fast plod
 , , ,T, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

5
Fast plod
 , , ,T, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

Comment: `tPtr` in main is never modified, so it always points to the first element.

Comment: OT: `srand` should be called in `main`. If you call it in `turtleMove`, the random number will only change once per second.

Answer (score 1):

You are only updating the *local* value of `tPtr`.

Your function is defined as:

```
void turtleMove(char raceTrack[SIZE], char *tPtr);
```

This takes a pointer to a `char` as the second argument, so anything at the address pointed to by `tPtr` can be modified and retained, but the *value* of tPtr (the address itself), cannot.

To be able to modify the address, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer to `char`:

```
void turtleMove(char raceTrack[SIZE], char **tPtr);
```

Then in the function, when you want to modify the *character*, you dereference twice:

```
**tPtr = ' ';
```

And when you want to modify the *address*, you dereference once:

```
*tPtr += 3;
```

Lastly, of course, you have to fix how you are calling `turtleMove()` so that you are passing a `char**`. Fortunately, you can do this by just grabbing the address of `tPtr` as defined in `main()`:

```
turtleMove(raceTrack, &tPtr);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.